# "Vouloir" in passé composé or imparfait

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé, imparfait

> À l’âge de 34 ans, lors d'une procession à Troyes, en Champagne, elle a découvert
>   sa vocation de missionnaire et elle a voulu rejoindre la Nouvelle-France dont l'expansion était en pleine actualité.

In this sentence, why do they use "*a voulu*" , which is the "passé composé" instead of "*voulait*" which is the "imparfait"? Don't we need to use the "imparfait" for the state of mind ? Isn't that sentence saying that she "wants" to rejoin the new France?

Comment: I thought you were going to ask why they aren't using "passé simple"...

Answer (score 1):

Reading (and re-reading) of these references will help : [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4197), [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_de_l%27indicatif_en_fran%C3%A7ais), [grammaire](https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/les-valeurs-demploi-des-temps-simples-de-lindicatif.html). An explanation on the basis of what they tell us follows.

> (BDL) L’imparfait narratif (aussi appelé imparfait historique ou pittoresque) évoque un fait qui a eu lieu à un moment précis du passé, moment explicité dans la phrase par un complément. Cette façon d’évoquer un événement a un effet dramatique, car le fait passé est présenté comme s’il était en cours. La part d’inaccompli de l’action qu’implique l’imparfait permet d’évoquer implicitement les conséquences qu’entraînera cette action, ce que ne ferait pas le passé simple (ou le passé composé), forme habituelle dans de tels contextes.

The reason the author uses the "passé composé" is that he/she does not chose to make the action of "wanting to go to New-France"  an action that will announce conséquences, he/she does not chose to make it an action as momentous as would be the case with the "imparfait". Instead he/she choses one of the usual tenses for narrative purposes.

Narrative use

> (Wikipédia) L'imparfait est parfois employé dans la littérature à la place des temps de narration habituels tels que le passé simple ou le présent : c'est par exemple une des caractéristiques du style de Georges Simenon, mais aussi de Marcel Proust. 
>   « Quelques instants plus tard, Maigret descendait l’escalier, traversait le salon aux meubles disparates, gagnait la terrasse. » (La Nuit du carrefour)

In conclusion, you can say that the choice dépends on what aspect  the author wants to focus on; the sentence could have been written as follows;

- À l’âge de 34 ans, lors d'une procession à Troyes, en Champagne, elle découvrait sa vocation de missionnaire et elle voulait rejoindre la Nouvelle-France dont l'expansion était en pleine actualité.

However, you give a slightly different aspect to the various actions; the real question is in knowing what that difference is.

Answer (score 0):

The *passé composé* is correct here because 
1) you need to understand "vouloir" here more as taking a decision than a having a permanent state of mind
2) it is an action that happened on a unique, definite moment in the past: *lors d'une procession à Troyes*; this is the precise moment where the action of "vouloir" starts.

Compare with:

> Quand elle était jeune, elle voulait rejoindre la Nouvelle-France (no definite moment, but a long, indefinite period in the past)